# Sending JSON object as a post parameter using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm currently working on an iOS app, and recently I faced an obstacle, basically the API endpoint I'm trying to consume requires a JSON object as a POST parameter in this format.

```
{
  json: {
    product_report: [
      {
        "id_assigned_pos": someid,
        "id_user": someid,
        "number": somenumber,
      },
      {
        "id_assigned_pos": someid,
        "id_user": someid,
        "number": somenumber,
      },{
        "id_assigned_pos": someid,
        "id_user": someid,
        "number": somenumber,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to achieve this using Alamofire and swift 4.
I'd appreciate someone's help.
Thanks!

Comment: For a better solution, can you share the data structure used in the list?

Comment: @Kamran I'm using everything as String.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> You can try this one:

```
var dict : [String: Any] = [:]

dict["type"] = "Step"
dict["data"] = ["2015-08-02": 8574];

let params: [String: Any] = ["r_id": "someName",
                            "data": String.jsonString(data: dataDict)];
```

**Here jsonString is an extension of String**

```
static func jsonString(data : Any) -> String {

        var jsonString = "";

        do {

            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
            jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let parameters = [
    "json": [
        "product_report": [
            [
                "id_assigned_pos": 1,
                "id_user": 1,
                "number": 1
            ],
            [
                "id_assigned_pos": 1,
                "id_user": 1,
                "number": 1
            ],
            [
                "id_assigned_pos": 1,
                "id_user": 1,
                "number": 1
            ],
        ]
    ]
]


Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters:parameters, headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
    // Here is the response  
} `
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm trying to achieve this using data from realm database, do I have to build the parameters using dictionaries ?!

Comment: You should use Codable protocol and it will be done mostly automatically. There's a lot of tutorials about codable, just google it.